# In Postgres PL/pgSQL how do I check if a numeric value is in a list of allowed values?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a Postgres table with a column called `dosage` of type numeric.  I want to write a trigger to validate that dosage is an integer multiple of 3.75, the allowed values are 0, 3.75, 7.5... all the way up to and include 75.

So I have written a trigger like this.  Here I use `generate_series` to generate a list of allowed values and then check if the record's `dosage` field is among the allowed values.
But this isn't working.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION validate_dosage_value() returns trigger as $$
    DECLARE
      allowed_values numeric[];
    BEGIN
      allowed_values := (SELECT array_agg(i)::numeric[] from generate_series(0, 75, 3.75) as i)

      IF NEW.dosage NOT IN allowed_values THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'dosage contains an invalid value';
      END IF;

      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ language plpgsql;
```

Any idea how I can make this work?  (I know one alternative is to do a division and check the result, but I'm more interested in the array membership check approach.)

Comment: I would not put business logic in a hardcoded function or check constraint. Create a table with the values that are allowed and validate against that table. This gives you much more flexibility

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for your trigger should be something like this:

```
  IF NOT NEW.dosage = ANY(allowed_values) THEN
```

But why not use a check constraint?

```
create table drugs (
  id serial primary key,
  dosage float not null 
    check (    dosage >= 0 
           and dosage <= 75 
           and floor(dosage/3.75) = ceiling(dosage/3.75))
);
CREATE TABLE

insert into drugs (dosage) values (-1);
ERROR:  new row for relation "drugs" violates check constraint "drugs_dosage_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, -1).

insert into drugs (dosage) values (3.75);
INSERT 0 1

insert into drugs (dosage) values (7.50);
INSERT 0 1

insert into drugs (dosage) values (7);
ERROR:  new row for relation "drugs" violates check constraint "drugs_dosage_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 7).

insert into drugs (dosage) values (75);
INSERT 0 1

insert into drugs (dosage) values (78.75);
ERROR:  new row for relation "drugs" violates check constraint "drugs_dosage_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, 78.75).
```

Comment: I like your solution of using `floor` and `ceiling`.  It's simpler and therefore more maintainable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works, good it's also shorter and do away with a local variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_dosage_value() returns trigger as $$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.dosage NOT IN (SELECT generate_series(0, 75, 3.75)) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'dosage contains an invalid value';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ language plpgsql;
```